# Local integer values changing randomly inside while loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I have a function which does some array manipulation on an NSMutableArray. Somehow after a couple of loops of the while function the values inside 2 local variables are total garbage. They are not being assigned or manipulated anywhere. Here's how:

[image]

Here's the function:

```
-(void) normalize_path:(NSMutableArray *)path tool:(Tool)tool
{
    NSUInteger last_accepted_point_index = 0;
    NSUInteger current_point_index = 1;

    while(current_point_index < [path count]){

        VPoint * p1, * p2;
        [[path objectAtIndex:last_accepted_point_index] getValue:&p1];
        [[path objectAtIndex:current_point_index] getValue:&p2];

        //float distance = [self distance_between:p1 and:p2];

//        if(distance < MIN_POINT_DISTANCE){
//            [path removeObjectAtIndex:current_point_index];
//        }else{
//            float opacity = tool.max_opacity - distance * tool.opacity_sensitivity;
//            opacity = opacity <= tool.min_opacity ? tool.min_opacity : opacity;
//            p2->opacity = opacity;
//            float thickness = tool.max_thickness - distance * tool.thickness_sensitivity;
//            thickness = thickness <= tool.min_thickness ? tool.min_thickness : thickness;
//            p2->thickness = thickness;
//            last_accepted_point_index = current_point_index;
//            //current_point_index++;
//        }
    }
}
```

And it's called only in one place like so:

```
//...
[self normalize_path:opath tool:pen];
//...
```

Every run creates different values. I am confounded! What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this may be a memory issue which you can fix by removing the `&` from in front of `p1` and `p2` in the `getValue:` call. It's difficult to be totally sure as you haven't said what `VPoint` is, but normally this code would look like this:

```
    VPoint p1, p2;
    [[path objectAtIndex:last_accepted_point_index] getValue:&p1];
    [[path objectAtIndex:current_point_index] getValue:&p2];
```

This would then set `p1` and `p2` to the actual values. Your distance between function would then not take references but the actual values of p1 and p2 (if you want to pass references as you are doing now, you'd put `&` in front of `p1` and `p2` in the distance `callBetween` method call.

Comment: Of course! Sometimes it's just tunnel vision. Thanks so much.

Comment: It's always easier to spot these things when it's not your code/the code of just written!